# About spring aop around advice return a struts request

Tags: spring, struts2, aop

Everyone, I have a problem with spring aop. When I use the around advice based on the configuration file, it will return a strust request. But it doesn't work. The blow shows:

`public Object invoke(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable
    {
        return joinPoint.proceed();  //this will return 'addEmp';
    }`

And the struts.xml like this:

```
<action name="xxxx" class="xxx">
        <result name="addEmp">pers_xxx.action</result>
    </action>
```

How I do this?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Spring AOP is basically an Interceptor. Struts2 already has a nice Interceptor Stack. Why do you need to use AOP ? Just use existing Struts2 Interceptors or write a custom one.

Comment: Thanks for reading. But I think it is the Freemaker giving rise to this question. Thanks.